# how to get the datepicker date as Date, not string?

Tags: database, angular, datepicker

i'm using angular 4 and i'm using ng2-jalali-date-picker and this is the html code:

```
          <dp-date-picker
            dir="ltr"
            mode="daytime"
            placeholder="{{'incoming.date' | translate}}"
            theme="dp-material"
            [formControl]="form.controls['incoming_mail_date']">
          </dp-date-picker>
```

i want to save the value ad Date in database. but i get string as the type. how can i get it as Date?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`new Date`** and pass the model variable as a parameter,

```
let newDate = new Date(incoming_mail_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

try add `[(ngModel)]="dateObject"` attribute to dp-date-picker.

dateObject is a Date variable that you must be define it.